# How to include related models using Django Rest Framework ListAPIView

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

Having 2 models and i need a list, a single queryset of lists that will combine all related fields from the 2 models.

```
class Product(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(...)
     price= models.Decimal(...)
     image = models.ImageField(...)
     description2 = models.TextField(....)

class Order(models.Model):
     buyer = models.CharField(...)
     product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

have it return something that includes the full related model. A queryset Lists of ORDER with this result

```
   {
    "id": 1,
    "buyer": 1,       
    "product": 3,
    "name": "Product 1",
    "image": "url",
    "price": 10.50
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "buyer": 2,       
    "product": 2,
    "name": "Product 2",
    "image": "url",
    "price": 6.50
  },
```

OR

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "buyer": 1,       
    "product": [
    {
       'id': 1,
       'name': 'Product 1',
       'image': "url",
       'price': 10.50
    }], 
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "buyer": 2,       
    "product": [
    {
       'id': 2,
       'name': 'Product 2',
       'image': "url",
       'price': 6.50
    }], 
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to define the serializer in serializers.py file.

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Product, Order

class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = "__all__"
        model = Product

class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    product = ProductSerializer(read_only = True)
    
    class Meta:
        fields = ("buyer", "product", )
        model = Order
```

And then, you need to create the ListAPIView for Order in views.py file.

```
from rest_framework import generics, mixins
from .models import Order
from .serializers import OrderSerializer

class OrderView(mixins.ListModelMixin, generics.GenericAPIView):
    queryset = Order.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OrderSerializer

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
         return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Last you need to add the api url in urls.py,

```
from .views import *
urlpatterns = [
    path('orders', OrderView.as_view(), name="order")
]
```

Comment: I got error response of AssertionError: Expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse` to be returned from the view, but received a `<class 'NoneType'>`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to return in `get` function of `OrderView` class. I changed the code. So please check it out.

Comment: How would you change this if let's say every order can have multiple products and you want to return only the 2 most expensive products with each order? How not to create n+1 queries to lookup for the 2 products for each order?